# Add second marker on google maps javascript code

Tags: google-maps, marker

This is my code and i want to add a second marker on it. I'm not experienced on javascript and i couldn't figure out a way to do it. I'ld love some explain also!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXXX, YY.YYYYYY),
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                      mapOptions);

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXXX, YY.YYYYYY);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: "'. $xmladd .'"
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function () {
            var center = map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            map.setCenter(center);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What problems did you run in to? You should be able to duplicate the code for the first marker (changing the position appropriately).

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the code for the first marker, changing the position appropriately.

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
      mapOptions);

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "'. $xmladd .'"
    });
    var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.735657, -74.1723667);
    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng2,
      map: map,
      title: "'. $xmladd2 .'"
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center);
  });
</script>
```